# Make React-table TS to be working in local computer with VS code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, react-table

Goal:
Make React-table to be working with typescript in my local computer.

Problem:
The code is based on this page  https://codesandbox.io/s/gkzg3?file=/src/makeData.ts

When I tried apply the code in my local computer I get som error.

How to solve these error?

```
ERROR in src/App.tsx:7:18

TS7031: Binding element 'columns' implicitly has an 'any' type.
     5 | import makeData from './makeData';
     6 |
  >  7 | function Table({ columns, data }) {
       |                  ^^^^^^^
     8 |   const {
     9 |     getTableProps,
    10 |     getTableBodyProps,



ERROR in src/App.tsx:7:27

TS7031: Binding element 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type.
     5 | import makeData from './makeData';
     6 |
  >  7 | function Table({ columns, data }) {
       |                           ^^^^
     8 |   const {
     9 |     getTableProps,
    10 |     getTableBodyProps,


ERROR in src/makeData.ts:26:34

TS7019: Rest parameter 'lens' implicitly has an 'any[]' type.
    24 | }
    25 |
  > 26 | export default function makeData(...lens) {
       |                                  ^^^^^^^
    27 |   const makeDataLevel = (depth: number = 0) => {
    28 |     const len = lens[depth];
    29 |     return range(len).map(d => {


TS7023: 'makeDataLevel' implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a return type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in one of its return expressions.
    25 |
    26 | export default function makeData(...lens) {
  > 27 |   const makeDataLevel = (depth: number = 0) => {
       |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    28 |     const len = lens[depth];
    29 |     return range(len).map(d => {
    30 |       return {
```

[image]

[image]

Info:
*I'm not used to react-table.
*It is the same code from this page (https://codesandbox.io/s/gkzg3?file=/src/makeData.ts). It works at sandbox but not in local computer with usage of VS code.
*It is typescript that is used.

Thank you

---

App.tsk

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { useTable } from 'react-table';
import makeData from './makeData';

function Table({ columns, data }) {
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow
  } = useTable({
    columns, data
  })
  // Render the UI for your table
  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
              <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map((row, i) => {
          prepareRow(row)
          return (
            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
              {row.cells.map(cell => {
                return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
              })}
            </tr>
          )
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}


export default function App() {
  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: 'Name',
        columns: [
          {
            Header: 'First Name',
            accessor: 'firstName',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Last Name',
            accessor: 'lastName',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        Header: 'Info',
        columns: [
          {
            Header: 'Age',
            accessor: 'age',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Visits',
            accessor: 'visits',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Status',
            accessor: 'status',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Profile Progress',
            accessor: 'progress',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    []
  )

  const data = React.useMemo(() => makeData(20), []);
  return (
    <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
  );
}
```

---

makeData.ts

```
import namor from 'namor';

const range = (len: number) => {
  const arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++){
    arr.push(i);
  }
  return arr;
}

const newPerson = () => {
  const statusChange = Math.random();
  return {
    firstName: namor.generate({ words: 1, numbers: 0}), 
    lastName: namor.generate({ words: 1, numbers: 0}),
    age: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30),
    visits: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    progress: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    status:
      statusChange > 0.66 ?
        'relationship' : statusChange > 0.33 ?
        'complicated' : 'single'
  }
}

export default function makeData(...lens) {
  const makeDataLevel = (depth: number = 0) => {
    const len = lens[depth];
    return range(len).map(d => {
      return {
        ...newPerson(),
        subRows: lens[depth + 1] ? makeDataLevel(depth + 1) : undefined,
      }
    })
  }

  return makeDataLevel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was lucky that it was working in my local computer in relation react TS.

*Must install these two via npm  "@types/react-table" and "react-table"
*https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-vk79wd

---

app.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useTable, Column, useSortBy } from 'react-table';
import axios from 'axios';

const columns: Column<Data>[] = [
  {
    Header: 'login',
    accessor: 'login',
  },
  {
    Header: 'id',
    accessor: 'id',
  },
  {
    Header: 'node id',
    accessor: 'node_id',
  },
  {
    Header: 'type',
    accessor: 'type',
  },
];

interface Data {
  login: number;
  id: string;
  node_id: string;
  type: string;
}

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  React.useMemo(
    () =>
      handleData().then((res) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          setData(res);
        }, 1000);
      }),
    []
  );

  const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } =
    useTable<Data>({ columns, data }, useSortBy);

  async function handleData() {
    const handleDataaa = async () => {
      const resp = await axios.get('https://api.github.com/users');
      return await resp.data;
    };

    return Promise.resolve(handleDataaa());
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    handleData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
              <th {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}>
                {console.log(column.getSortByToggleProps())}
                {column.render('Header')}
                <span>
                  {' '}
                  {column.isSorted
                    ? column.isSortedDesc
                      ? ' '
                      : ' '
                    : ''}{' '}
                </span>
              </th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map((row, i) => {
          prepareRow(row);
          return (
            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
              {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>;
              })}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
        {rows.length === 0 && (
          <tr>
            <td colSpan={2}>loading...</td>
          </tr>
        )}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

---

react-table.d.tsx

```
import {
  UseSortByColumnOptions,
  UseSortByColumnProps,
  UseSortByInstanceProps,
  UseSortByOptions,
  UseSortByState,
} from 'react-table';

declare module 'react-table' {
  export interface TableOptions<D extends object> extends UseSortByOptions<D> {}

  export interface TableInstance<D extends object = {}>
    extends UseSortByInstanceProps<D> {}

  export interface TableState<D extends object = {}>
    extends UseSortByState<D> {}

  export interface Column<D extends object = {}>
    extends UseSortByColumnOptions<D> {}

  export interface ColumnInstance<D extends object = {}>
    extends UseSortByColumnProps<D> {}
}
```

---

Comment: Updated version:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-2g8ntn